# Angular(6)'s Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ICurrentWeatherData'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, karma-jasmine

When working with Angular6 the Error happens, though my app can be running and working properly, the tests will not pass. Here's the code snippet of the file:

```
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'
import { ICurrentWeather } from '../interfaces'

@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getCurrentWeather(city: string, country: string): Observable<ICurrentWeather> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<ICurrentWeatherData>(
        `${environment.baseUrl}api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?` +
          `q=${city},${country}&appid=${environment.appId}`
      )
      .pipe(map(data => this.transformToICurrentWeather(data)))
  }

  private transformToICurrentWeather(data: ICurrentWeatherData): ICurrentWeather {
    return {
      city: data.name,
      country: data.sys.country,
      date: data.dt * 1000,
      image: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`,
      temperature: this.convertKelvinToFahrenheit(data.main.temp),
      description: data.weather[0].description,
    }
  }
  private convertKelvinToFahrenheit(kelvin: number): number {
    return (kelvin * 9) / 5 - 459.67
  }
}`
```

- ERROR in src/app/weather/weather.service.ts(14,12): error TS2304:
  Cannot find name 'ICurrentWeatherData'.
- src/app/weather/weather.service.ts(21,44): error TS2304: Cannot find 
  name 'ICurrentWeatherData'.

Comment: where is define observer class for  `ICurrentWeatherData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't import ICurrentWeatherData, in interfaces import I only see ICurrentWeather

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

u should import that interface 
i thinks to that's works when u replace 
this :

```
import { ICurrentWeather } from '../interfaces'
```

to :

```
import { ICurrentWeather } from '../interfaces/ICurrentWeather'
```

Comment: Assuming interfaces is a folder, the import should be import { ICurrentWeather, ICurrentWeatherData } from '../interfaces'. With your solution ICurrentWeatherData is still not imported

Comment: ohh yep, really